# Use jquery to move sub-menu down, how much depends on how many list items

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a menu that when a menu item is clicked and it has a sub-menu, it will move the current items in the list down and slide the sub-menu into position. The only issue is I only want the list items after the one clicked to move down

I'm trying to create a sliding menu that when you click a list item and it has a sub-menu, the list items after the one clicked will move down and the sub-menu will slide into place just below the list item that was clicked. The thing is I only want the further list items to move down depending on the size of the sub-menu.

Here's the jquery I already have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.button-wrapper').click(function(e) {
    $('.menu > li:nth-child(1)').toggleClass('first');
    $('.menu > li:nth-child(2)').toggleClass('second');
    $('.menu > li:nth-child(3)').toggleClass('third');
    $('.menu > li:nth-child(4)').toggleClass('fourth');
    $('.menu > li:nth-child(5)').toggleClass('fifth');
    $('.sub-menu li').removeClass('sub-first');
    $('.sub-menu li').removeClass('sub-second');
    $('.sub-menu li').removeClass('sub-third');
});

$(".menu a").click(function(e) {
    if($(this).next('.sub-menu').length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.sub-menu > li:nth-child(1)').toggleClass('sub-first');
        $('.sub-menu > li:nth-child(2)').toggleClass('sub-second');
        $('.sub-menu > li:nth-child(3)').toggleClass('sub-third');
        $('.sub-menu').closest('li').next().toggleClass('daniel');
    }
    else  {
        return true
    }
});

});
```

I've attached a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uNuKF/ to show you want i currently have. You'll notice that all sub menus slide but I only want the one that was clicked to slide which doesn't include future sub-menus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, but your function is finding all .sub-menu items not just the appropriate  child ones:

Change:

```
$('.sub-menu > li:nth-child(1)').toggleClass('sub-first');
... etc
```

For:

```
$(this).next('.sub-menu').find('li:nth-child(1)').toggleClass('sub-first');
... etc
```

[This updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uNuKF/2/) includes the above fix and a reveal animation.

Comment: Thanks, checked out the fiddle and that's exactly what i wanted, just need to make an alteration when you click one the other one closes which i'm sure will be simple, but thanks. Started learning jquery last week and i'm having fun doing it. Thanks